# How to add additional data to a notification object in react-native-push-notification on ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification

Any idea how to add additional data to a notification object in react-**native-push-notification** on ios?

Currently I'm sending this as the body:

```
body = { aps: { alert: "Text that is sent in the notification.", sound: "default", badge: 1 } }.to_json
```

I can't figure out how to add additional data that wouldn't be shown in the notification alert such as a user id to redirect the user to the correct view if he clicks on the notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another property to the body to pass additional data :

```
body = { 
    aps: {
      alert: "Text that is sent in the notification.",
      sound: "default",
      badge: 1 
    },
    userId: "6446qf45qsdg",
}
```

See [Creating the Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) from apple docs for more info about this.

Comment: hello, when i write timestamp and save it into DB i got this in cloud functions `message: 'Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.timestamp" property. Values must be strings.'` @Dyo